# If you poison a ration of water, will you be able to put it into the well?

Tags: die2nite

I'm talking about die2nite, of course, and I ask out of curiousity since I've seen that someone in my town has the corrosive liquid and the cyanide.

I know that when you turn corrosive liquid into vial of poison, it can poison food and/or water, but I'm not sure if the cyanide can. My main concern is him (or her) trying to poison the main water source. I want to know if it's possible so I can tell everyone to stop it before it happens.

This player has been very troublesome and I wouldn't be surprised by this, seeing as how he/she has these items now...

Answer (score 3):

The [vial of poison](http://die2nitewiki.com/wiki/Vial_of_Poison) can only be used to poison Suspicious-looking Vegetables, Fleshroom Puree, Anabolic Steroids, Open Cans, or Water Rations. Poisoned water rations cannot be added into the well poison it[.](http://die2nitewiki.com/wiki/Cyanide)